# C++ basics: unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, arduino, overloading, overload-resolution

I am quite new to C++, and probably I had naive problems. I know that there are other smilar questions, but are related to (seems to me) a more complex problems than mine. 
I am trying to make a firmware for Arduino, using C++ and I've hurt myself with the overloading errors.

I have this code define in a cpp file:

```
void class1::functionA(void)
{
  object2.functionOfClass2(class1::functionB);
}
```

The class1 is initialized as:

```
class class1
{
 public:
 void functionA(void);
 void functionB(void);
 private:
}
```

And in the compilation gives

```
no matching function for call to 'class2::functionOfClass2(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

***Translating into the practical:***

in my code I am using the **Wire** library inside a member function of the **class1** for an Arduino library, where in the example the **object2** and **class2** are respectively the ***Wire*** object of class ***TwoWire***.

I have the need to call the **wire** library inside a member function of my **class1**. 
This solution is a consequence of a previous lessons, in which I learnt that I cannot call a member function of **class1** inside a non-member function, because the instantiation of the non-member function cannot be made since the class is not instantiated as an object yet, and the compiler has no clue on how to do this.

But calling the **Wire.** object inside a member function, I thought that was possible. But thinking better to it, actually, when passing the **class1** member function pointer to the **Wire** function, the compiler cannot know what to pass to **wire**, and so the following is WRONG:

```
void class1::functionA(void)
{
  Wire.onRequest(class1::functionB); //wrong
}
```

where the **onRequest** accept `void (*)(void)` functions.

So trying with

```
void class1::functionA(void)
{
  Wire.onRequest(&class1::functionB); //wrong
}
```

The error became:

> error: no matching function for call to 'TwoWire::onRequest(void
>   (class1::*)())'
>       candidates are: void TwoWire::onRequest(void (*)())

There is a way to make those things work? If I say *static* and *initializer list*, am I on the right way with the right keywords?

Comment: Had to delete my answer. I don't think this is plainly doable. You need to pass `this` of your `class1` instance to `onRequest`, and you just can't do that if it accepts `void (*)()` (no parameters allowed). A well-designed library would instead define `onRequest` as `onRequest(void (*callback)(void*), void* context)` instead, and you would pass `this` as `context`.

Comment: The only way to do this is if there's only one `class1` instance in your whole application - then you can substitute this instance unconditionally and call `functionB` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&class1::functionB` is a pointer-to-member-function, not a pointer-to-function. Its type is `void (class1::*)(void)`, not `void (*)(void)`, as expected by the `onRequest` method. It means that to call this pointer-to-member-function, it is required to have the instance as well (`class1*`).

If the `class1` is a singleton, the easiest way to solve this is probably making `functionB` a static member or simply a non-member function (not inside any class).

If `class1` cannot be assumed singleton, then the library must have a way to pass a context pointer (usually `void*`) along the pointer-to-function and this context is a parameter of the callback function. You should pass `this` as the context and a pointer to a wrapper function, like the following:

```
void wrapper_for_class1_functionB(void* context)
{
    static_cast<class1*>(context)->functionB();
}

void class1::functionA(void)
{
    Wire.onRequest(&wrapper_for_class1_functionB, this);
}
```

Comment: The goal is not to make it singleton, infact also the data structures are defined in the class. This means that I can't use a non-member function since it contains data handling of structures defined in the class.

Comment: I then tried with your suggestion, seems very interesting, but this requires, again, to modify the Wire library to take another argument. In fact, the error that I got is a non matching function. Am I missing something?

Comment: And anyway, also the functions in the "functionB()" there are other member functions that need to be called outside the .cpp, so in the main file, when the object is created.

Comment: If the library doesn't provide a context argument that is passed back with the callback, then it is impossible for the user code that installed the callback to know in which context the callback is fired, simply because the callback doesn't receive the context. And [`Wire::onRequest`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireOnRequest) doesn't provide it indeed. The best you can do is to save the context (the `this` pointer, in your case) in a global variable and make sure no two instances can wait for the callback simultaneously.